# Web server hosted in ECS got error of ERR_TIME_OUT / Malformed HTTP message?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, http, tornado, amazon-ecs

I created a web application using Python tornado. It runs well on my local machine - Chrome can access the page.

The application is dorkerized and deployed to ECS. However, browsing the ECS site in Chrome got ERR_TIME_OUT. And the ECS Task Logging shows

> 2021-02-20 06:31:152021-02-20 11:31:15 INFO MainThread http1connection.py Malformed HTTP message from 10.1.2.1: Malformed HTTP version in HTTP Request-Line: ''

> 2021-02-20 06:30:302021-02-20 11:30:30 INFO MainThread http1connection.py Malformed HTTP message from 10.1.2.1: Malformed HTTP version in HTTP Request-Line: ''

> 2021-02-20 06:29:452021-02-20 11:29:45 INFO MainThread http1connection.py Malformed HTTP message from 10.1.2.1: no colon in header line

> 2021-02-20 06:29:092021-02-20 11:29:09 INFO MainThread http1connection.py Malformed HTTP message from 10.1.2.1: no colon in header line

> 2021-02-20 06:29:082021-02-20 11:29:08 INFO MainThread http1connection.py Malformed HTTP message from 10.1.2.1: Malformed HTTP version in HTTP Request-Line: 'ªª\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03À+À/À,À0Ì©Ì¨À\x13À\x14\x00\x9c\x00\x9d\x00/\x005\x01\x00\x01\x93'

> 2021-02-20 06:26:032021-02-20 11:26:03 INFO MainThread http1connection.py Malformed HTTP message from 10.1.2.1: no colon in header line

> 2021-02-20 06:25:292021-02-20 11:25:29 INFO MainThread http1connection.py Malformed HTTP message from 10.1.2.1: Malformed HTTP request line

Comment: Are you sending requests over `https`? If so, could you try just `http` (without `s`)?

Comment: Now the error is gone. `https://elb_url` got timeout but `http://elb_url:443` works.